# PyPI 400 upload error

Tags: python-2.7, version, packaging, pypi

I created a package in PyPI named virtdc. I made some changes and uploaded 2 different versions 0.1.0 and 0.1.1. Now I deleted version 0.1.1 through the PyPI web interface and try to upload again with the same version number. It is giving me error as follows

```
...
Writing virtdc-0.1.2/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'virtdc-0.1.2' (and everything under it)
running register
Registering virtdc to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
running upload
Submitting dist/virtdc-0.1.2.tar.gz to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (400): This filename has previously been used, you should use a different version.
```

And PyPI does not allow more than 4 versions for a package. So we have to delete some versions and upload again.

Even after this upload error the rst content description is available. But download link is not available. You can find my package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtdc)

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks

Comment: See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.distutils.devel/22739 "I've pushed changes to PyPI where it is no longer possible to reuse a filename and attempting to do it will give an 400 error"

Comment: The (similar or) same discussion on the [packaging-problems issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/74) on GitHub. -- TL;DR No fix for this PyPI behavior up until today.

Comment: I meet this problem if I upload `bdist_wininst` `exe` format file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it seems there is no straight fix:

http://sourceforge.net/p/pypi/support-requests/468

However, if you want to upload a source distribution, there is a workaround which is not too ugly. You can build a "zip" archive instead of a "tar.gz" archive. You can control this e.g. via

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=zip
```

This way, you obtain a different file name. Then you might append the upload command directly

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=zip upload
```

Or you might use [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) to upload after building:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

Comment: I also saw the suggestion to release a `.post1` version.  That's a PEP440 compliant post-release version for very minor fixes (like fixing the issue you're talking about).

Comment: as pointed out by @Pryce http://stackoverflow.com/a/32443905/1816995 this no longer works.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

1. Delete the `build`, `dist`, and `<package name>.egg-info` folders in your root directory.
2. Change version number in your `setup.py` file.
3. Create distribution again. e.g: `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
4. Upload distribution again. e.g: `twine upload dist/*`
5. enjoy! :-)

Comment: We should note deleting is critical..running `setup.py` doesn't overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question but for binary packages. A fix for binary packages is to append a build tag to the version number, e.g. rename `mypkg-1.2.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` to `mypkg-1.2.3-1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`. This behaviour is documented at https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention:

> build tag:
> Optional build number. Must start with a digit. Acts as a tie-breaker if two wheel file names are the same in all other respects (i.e. name, version, and other tags). Sort as an empty tuple if unspecified, else sort as a two-item tuple with the first item being the initial digits as an int, and the second item being the remainder of the tag as a str.

This is better than appending `.post1` as mentioned in another comment, since that is considered a different version number by `pip` so users must change their `requirements.txt` etc., which was not acceptable for me. Appending `-1`, however, is considered by `pip` to be the same version.

This solution probably does not work with source distributions since they don't have a "build" like binaries do. So this might not exactly answer the OP, but since this SO question came up a lot while searching for an answer for binaries, I thought it was worth posting here.