# Setting up python package

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, pypi

I am having a fair bit of trouble setting up my python package.

I am trying to make it installable via pip by using PYPI.

This is what my project structure looks like:

```
     |-scum
      \
       | LICENSE
       | MANIFEST
       | README.md
       | README.rst
       | scum
       | scum.py
       | setup.py
       |
       |- |modules
       |   \ 
       |    | __init__.py
       |    | browse.py
       |    | popup.py
       |    | term.py
       |
       |- |resources
       |   \  
       |    | config.txt
       |    | help.txt
       |    | start_up.txt
       |    | tabs.dat
```

I need to be able to import the files in `modules` and I need my main file `scum.py` to be able to access the files in `resources`

This is my setup.py:

```
import sys

from distutils.core import setup

from pkgutil import walk_packages

import modules
import resources

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    sys.exit("Scum requires Python 3.")

VERSION = '0.2'

setup_kwargs = {
    "version": VERSION,
    "description": 'Scum text editor',
    "author": 'Christian Careaga',
    "author_email": 'christian.careaga7@gmail.com',
    "url": 'https://github.com/CCareaga/scum',
    "download_url": "https://github.com/CCareaga/scum/zipball/" + VERSION,
   "classifiers": [
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Topic :: Utilities",
    "Topic :: Text Editors",
    ],
   "data_files": [("", ['README.rst']),
               ("resources", ['config.txt', 'help.txt', 'start_up.txt', 'tabs.dat'])]
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='scum',
        py_modules=['scum'],
        scripts=['scum'],
        packages = ['modules'],
        include_package_data=True,
        long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
        **setup_kwargs
        )
```

This setup.py file is not working, I changed a few things since I tested it but I can't figure out how to upload a new version of my package with out creating a whole new tag and release number.

Any help would be appreciated, I have had trouble finding good documentation on this that isn't for very basic packages.

Comment: What error do you get? And from where?

Comment: @RichArt Well, I can register and upload it but then when I try to install I was getting an error saying that there was no module resources, so I took that out of course. Now i tried to re-upload and pip tells me there is no version matching for what I am requesting (v0.2) but it is on the pypi site. I basically need to be guided through this because I can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

I had not the same problem, but a similar one. To solve it I just deleted the PyPi release and also deleted the auto generated files by the setup.py file (I had several version files in a folder) and just re-uploaded everything with twine.

You may try it out, but I guess you also have to change the version number!

See also my answer here: [PyPI 400 upload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708705/pypi-400-upload-error) . It may help you.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful! I figured I could just clear it out and re-upload. I also figured out that I can just run `python setup.py install` and it will do the same thing pip would do. Now I am getting some pretty odd errors coming from actually running the program...

Comment: Oh! I got it working! the script was being run by bash rather than python I think... I need `#!/usr/bin/env python`... silly me! Thank you!